# html prevent scrolling also prevents html5 input type range

Tags: html, html-input

I have an html web app, and I am adding sliders like so:

```
<form oninput="output1.value=slider1.value">
  <input type="range" name="slider1" value="50"/>
  <output name="output1" for="slider1">50</output>
</form>
```

Works great on web, and on device.

Now, when i add in the preventdefault code to stop page scrolling it breaks:

```
document.addEventListener( 'touchmove' , function(e) {e.preventDefault()} , false );
```

Now, if this was my own control, I could fix it, but I want the default behavior of the html5 slider, how can I get that back?

Comment: just thought of something, maybe i can check the event's owner, if its a slider, let it pass

Answer (score 1):

Not sure this could be a duplicate, but just in case:

```
function stopScrolling( touchEvent ) {
    if ((touchEvent.target.id != "pastGenSlider") && (touchEvent.target.id != "curGenSlider"))
        touchEvent.preventDefault(); 
}
document.addEventListener( 'touchmove' , stopScrolling , false );
```

Just check what id the element has, and if it is something you want to allow it to process, just let it pass/do not call preventDefault();